# getting events from table according to date

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, user, courses and usertocourse

In **user** table, the fields are given below

```
| id         | name       |   email   |
```

**courses** table

```
| course_id | name  |description| enrollment_key  |
```

enrollment_key  is 1 for self enrolled courses, enrollment_key  is 0 for admin assigned courses.

**usertocourse**

```
| user_id    | course_id  | assigndate | completiondate | started |
```

when a admin assign a course to user, it will come to this table, or if the user self enrolled also it will come to this table. Started bit is set to 1 only when the user started the courses, else its 0.
For self assigned course the completion date is automatically set to some default date say(2000-11-30)

Now what I need is two things

1. I need to get the list of all courses to that user_id from usertocourse
   table(both self enrolled and assigned courses), and the list of all self enrolled courses from course table except the once which the user is already enrolled.

   ```
   SELECT a.*, b.*
   FROM courses a 
   JOIN users_to_courses b
   WHERE a.course_id=b.course_id
   and b.user_id='$user_id'
   ```

   The above query returns all the courses, but it does nt check whether it is already assigned or not. I need a query which can check both together.
2. I have a date with me say '2016-07-01', I want to display all the courses which of that month. The below given query works fine if assign date and completion date are in same month, say if the course is starting on 2016-06-28 and completiondate is 2016-07-05, the query will not work as am comparing the $date with assign date.

   ```
   SELECT a.*,b.*
   FROM courses a
   JOIN users_to_courses b
   WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM b.`assign_date`) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM '$date')
   AND b.`user_id` = '$user_id'
   and a.enrollment_key='0'
   and b.completion_date!='2000-11-30'
   and a.course_id = b.course_id
   ```

Comment: General comment: A picture is worth a thousand words, especially for SQL questions on Stack Overflow.  Show us sample data and the output you want, and it will make it easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Your this line is not clear  from 1st question: " the list of all self enrolled courses from course table except the once which the user is already enrolled." For 2nd question "I want to display all the courses which of that month" what you want to say? course's start date or completion date should math the provided date?